# Como puedo aplicar una refactorizacion a mi codigo en javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones, javascript-metodo

estoy aprendiendo javascript y mis coach me han sugerido refactorizar este código, realmente desconozco como puedo hacerlo, me gustaria me orientaran o mostraran ejemplos de como hacerlo o como podria quedar aplicandole una refactorización.

En esta funcion lo que hago es crear un nuevo objeto a partir de uno ya existente, extrayendo datos y usandolos para alimentar el nuevo objeto creado.

Solo puedo usar vanilla JS

```js
console.time("total")
const computeDataTwo = (datos) => {
  const mapAthletes = new Map();
  for (let j = 0; j < datos.length; j++) {
    const element = datos[j];
    if (!mapAthletes.has(element.name)) {
      const initValueAthletes = {
        gold: 0,
        bronze: 0,
        silver: 0,
        total: 0
      }
      mapAthletes.set(element.name + " " + element.team, initValueAthletes)
    }
  }

  for (let j = 0; j < datos.length; j++) {
    const element = datos[j];
    const athletes = mapAthletes.get(element.name + " " + element.team);
    if (element.medal === "Gold") {
      athletes.gold = athletes.gold + 1;
    }
    if (element.medal === "Bronze") {
      athletes.bronze = athletes.bronze + 1;
    }
    if (element.medal === "Silver") {
      athletes.silver = athletes.silver + 1;
    }
    athletes.total = athletes.total + 1;
    mapAthletes.set(element.name + " " + element.team, athletes)

  }

  const arrayAthletes = [];
  mapAthletes.forEach((value, key) => {
    const totalMedalByAthletes = {
      name: key,
      gold: value.gold,
      silver: value.silver,
      bronce: value.bronze,
      total: value.total
    };
    arrayAthletes.push(totalMedalByAthletes);

  })
  return arrayAthletes
}
let datos = [{name:"pepe", team:"equipo1", medal: "Gold"},{name:"juan", team:"equipo2"}]
console.log(computeDataTwo(datos))
console.timeEnd("total")
```

Comment: si agregas un ejemplo del set de datos es mas facil.

Comment: Fijate si podes completar let datos = {} con un objeto ejemplo, y definir totalMedals para que quede funcionando, de esa forma es mas probable darte una mano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aca te dejo una pequeña refactorización del codigo, entiendo que hace todo lo mismo que estabas realizando, dejame saber si te es de utilidad.

```js
console.time("tiempo")
const computeDataTwo = (datos) => {
  return datos.map(atleta => {
    let respuesta = {
      nombre: atleta.name + " " + atleta.team,
      gold: 0,
      bronze: 0,
      silver: 0,
      total: 0
    }

    atleta?.medal != null && (respuesta[atleta.medal] += 1)

    respuesta.total = ["gold", "bronze", "silver"].reduce((acum, item) => respuesta[item] + acum, 0)

    return respuesta
  })

}

let datos = [{
  name: "pepe",
  team: "equipo1",
  medal: "gold"
}, {
  name: "juan",
  team: "equipo2"
}]

console.log(computeDataTwo(datos))
console.timeEnd("tiempo")
```

Y aqui te dejo otra con incluso menos vueltas.

```js
console.time("tiempo")
const computeDataTwo = (datos) => {
  
  return datos.map(atleta => {
    
    let respuesta = {
      nombre: atleta.name + " " + atleta.team,
      total:0,
    }
    let medals = ["gold", "bronze", "silver"]
    
    medals.forEach(medal => {
      respuesta[medal] = atleta.medal == medal ? 1 : 0
      respuesta.total += respuesta[medal] 
    })
    
    return respuesta
  })
  
}

let datos = [{name:"pepe", team:"equipo1", medal: "gold"},{name:"juan", team:"equipo2"}]

console.log(computeDataTwo(datos))
console.timeEnd("tiempo")
```

Y otra mas, reduciendo aun mas el codigo.

```js
console.time("tiempo")
const computeDataTwo = (datos) => {
  return datos.map(atleta => {
    let res = {
      nombre: atleta.name + " " + atleta.team,
      total: 0,
    };

    ["gold", "bronze", "silver"].forEach( medal => 
      res.total += res[medal] = atleta.medal == medal ? 1 : 0
    )
    return res
  })
}

let datos = [{
  name: "pepe",
  team: "equipo1",
  medal: "gold"
}, {
  name: "juan",
  team: "equipo2"
}]

console.log(computeDataTwo(datos))
console.timeEnd("tiempo")
```

Y como soy un manija, aca te dejo otra mas.

```js
console.time("tiempo")
const computeDataTwo = (datos, medallas = ["gold", "bronze", "silver"] ) => 
  datos.map(({name, team, medal, total = 0}) => {
    let res = {nombre : name + " " + team , total};
    medallas.forEach( medalla => res.total += res[medalla] = medal == medalla ? 1 : 0 )
    return res
  }
)

let datos = [{name:"pepe", team:"equipo1", medal: "gold"},{name:"juan", team:"equipo2"}]

console.log(computeDataTwo(datos))
console.timeEnd("tiempo")
```

Y la ultima pero ya se pone muy dificil de leer y no tiene ventajas en performance.

```js
console.time("total")
const computeDataTwo = (datos, medallas = ["gold", "bronze", "silver"] ) => 
  datos.map( ({ name, team, medal, total = 0, r = {nombre:name + " " + team, total} }) => {
      medallas.forEach( m => r.total += r[m] = m == medal ? 1 : 0 ) 
      return r
  }
)

let datos = [{name:"pepe", team:"equipo1", medal: "gold"},{name:"juan", team:"equipo2"}]

console.log(computeDataTwo(datos))
console.timeEnd("total")
```

Comment: oh! mil gracias por todas las opciones que me diste!!! voy a guardarlas para practicar e ir aprendiendo.... gracias gracias gracias

Answer (score 1):

ahi te dejo una opcion que se me ocurrio saludos!

```js
let datos = [{
  name: "pepe",
  team: "equipo1",
  medal: "Gold"
}, {
  name: "juan",
  team: "equipo2"
}, {
  name: "toto",
  team: "equipo1",
  medal: "Gold"
}]

const computeDataThree = (datos) => {
  let arrayAcomodado = datos.map(atleta => {
    let total = 0
    const totalizador = (valor) => {
      total++
      return valor
    }
    return {
      name: atleta.name + " " + atleta.team,
      gold: atleta.medal == "Gold" ? totalizador(1) : 0,
      silver: atleta.medal == "Silver" ? totalizador(1) : 0,
      bronce: atleta.medal == "Bronce" ? totalizador(1) : 0,
      total
    }
  })
  return arrayAcomodado
}
console.log(computeDataThree(datos))
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).